# Get error exception when using the sleep function

Tags: java, android

I want to delay my application for a while while a melody is playing, and when it's finished change the image on an imageview.

```
public void addListenerOnButtons() {    
    harmonicaTecknad= (ImageView)this.findViewById(R.id.harmonicatecknadspelautblas);
    harmonicaTecknad.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {            
        harmonicaTecknad.setImageResource(R.drawable.harmonicatecknadtryckrood);
        RunAnimations();
        utblas=MediaPlayer.create(SpelaTonerActivity.this, R.raw.utblas4);
        utblas.start();
        Thread timer = new Thread(){
            public void run() {
                try { // The delay should occur here
                    sleep(utblas.getDuration());
                } catch(InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    harmonicaTecknad.setImageResource(R.drawable.harmonicatecknad1);
                }
            }
        };
        timer.start();
    }
}
```

I get an exception error, obviously I cannot set the image inside the thread, so where should I set it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write `harmonicaTecknad.setImageResource(R.drawable.harmonicatecknad1);` code on UI thread because you can not write UI code to non UI thread.

So simply replace above line of code with

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    { 
            harmonicaTecknad.setImageResource(R.drawable.harmonicatecknad1);
    }
});
```

If you are still getting error then for testing purpose just change `sleep(utblas.getDuration());` with sleep(1000);

Answer (score 1):

This is all explained in details, with examples, in the [android documentation](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html):

> Android offers several ways to access the UI thread from other
>   threads. You may already be familiar with some of them but here is a
>   comprehensive list:
>
> - Activity.runOnUiThread(Runnable)
> - View.post(Runnable)
> - View.postDelayed(Runnable, long)
> - Handler
>
> [...]
>
> Unfortunately, these classes and methods could also tend to make your
>   code more complicated and more difficult to read. It becomes even
>   worse when your implement complex operations that require frequent UI
>   updates.
>
> To remedy this problem, Android 1.5 and later platforms offer a
>   utility class called AsyncTask, that simplifies the creation of
>   long-running tasks that need to communicate with the user interface.

Answer (score 0):

As the other answers say, you need to set the image from the UI thread. However, while you can use `Thread.sleep()`, you should in general avoid using sleeps for logic. Most classes have some way to get callbacks when things happen - for example in your case you can use `MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener`. You register for a callback from the media player, and that callback will always be on the UI thread. This is what it looks like:

```java
public void addListenerOnButtons() {    
    harmonicaTecknad= (ImageView)this.findViewById(R.id.harmonicatecknadspelautblas);
    harmonicaTecknad.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {            
      harmonicaTecknad.setImageResource(R.drawable.harmonicatecknadtryckrood);
      RunAnimations();
      utblas=MediaPlayer.create(SpelaTonerActivity.this, R.raw.utblas4);
      utblas.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
          @Override
          public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
              harmonicaTecknad.setImageResource(R.drawable.harmonicatecknad1);
          }
      };
      utblas.start();
    }
}
```